# Can't open downloaded files directly via Firefox Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, firefox

using Firefox under Xubuntu 18.04 I cannot open downloaded files directly via the "Open with..." option. I always have to save the file under downloads, go there and open it manually. Trying to open the file via the "Open with..." option I get the message eg. "tmp/mozilla/xyz.odt doesn't exist. It's the same under Chromium. Any hints...? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As it works for me (mainly downloading *.pdf) I guess it has something to do with *.odt.

Comment: Are you missing your `/tmp` folder?  If you are, try creating a new folder with `sudo mkdir -m 1777 /tmp`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I did a clear reinstall of Firefox, *.pdf are working now, but other files still don't. /tmp folder exists. To me it seems like Firefox having problems with properly accessing and saving files to /tmp, but I have no clue how to change that. I also reinstalled Chromium, there everything works fine now. So maybe I'll have to switch the browser...

Comment: In firefox, and probably most other browsers, you can change the default directory *where* to store downloaded files. (As for firefox, how to get to where to change this property seams to change whit every update (rant, rant, rant)). Possibly you have accidentally messed it up, using "tmp" instead of "/tmp".